# How to send a managed Exception from WCF client to server (for logging)?

Tags: wcf, serialization, exception

I'm trying to build an error logging mechanism for my WCF client applications, so they can report any exceptions that may occur outside of the WCF context back to the service.

I'm absolutely guaranteed in this situation that all clients will be .NET.

I'm finding a plethora of information, articles and examples on how to configure for going the other way (e.g. service to client), but nothing on client to service.

I wish to do something like this on the client:

```
Dim i As Integer

Try
  i = String.Empty

Catch ex As Exception
  Client.Create.Call(Sub(S As IService)
                       S.Log(LogLevels.Error, ex)
                     End Sub)

End Try
```

`FaultException(Of T)` doesn't work; I tried this:

```
Dim i As Integer

Try
  i = String.Empty

Catch ex As Exception
  Try
    Throw New FaultException(Of Exception)(ex)

  Catch fex As FaultException
    Client.Create.Call(Sub(S As IService)
                         S.Log(LogLevels.Error, fex.Message, fex)
                       End Sub)

  End Try
End Try
```

It returns a hideously obscure error message of its own:

> "Type 'System.InvalidCastException' with data contract name 'InvalidCastException:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer."

Binary serialization of the exception doesn't work either; I get an error at deserialization:

> "The input stream is not a valid binary format."

My code for that:

```
Class Test
  Public Sub Test
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim aEx As Byte()
    Dim oEx As Exception

    Try
      i = String.Empty

    Catch ex As Exception
      aEx = ex.ToBytes
      oEx = aEx.ToObject(Of Exception)()

    End Try
  End Sub
End Class

Public Module Generic
  <Extension>
  Public Function ToBytes(Of T)([Object] As T) As Byte()
    Using oStream As New MemoryStream
      With New BinaryFormatter
        .Serialize(oStream, [Object])
      End With

      Return oStream.ToArray
    End Using
  End Function



  <Extension>
  Public Function ToObject(Of T)(Data As Byte()) As T
    Using oStream As New MemoryStream
      oStream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length)
      oStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

      With New BinaryFormatter
        Return .Deserialize(oStream)
      End With
    End Using
  End Function
End Module
```

How does one send this non-WCF exception across the wire?

**EDIT**

Here's my service interface, edited for brevity:

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IService
  <OperationContract> Sub Log(Level As LogLevels, Message As String, Exception As Exception)
End Interface
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that was a trip and a half. Wish I'd brought some TrailMix.

The solution turned out to be Microsoft's red-headed stepchild, `NetDataContractSerializer`, mentioned briefly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192883/722393). You can read about why I call it that [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/04/15/datacontractserializer-vs-netdatacontractserializer.aspx).

There's an important link at the bottom of Ron Jacobs' post (to Aaron Skonnard's post) that's now expired. I found a copy of that [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100219113244/http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/04/21/22284.aspx) (the comments are important, have a look). It looks like [Tim Scott](https://lunaverse.wordpress.com/2007/05/09/remoting-using-wcf-and-nhibernate/) used a slight variation of Aaron's code as well.

It was in Tim's more thorough explanation that I found my Holy Grail. (I've been wanting to do this for some time!)

Tim is using `Attribute` decorations, but those are applicable only when working with CLR objects at the *server*. In this case we're working at the *client*.

So in the end, the fix is beautiful in its simplicity. Just use `NetDataContractSerializer` to package up the `System.Exception` into a `Byte()`, send the data to the server, and then deserialize it there. No chanting, smoke-n-mirrors, eye-of-the-newt required.

There's a performance penalty, so keep your `Exception`s to a minimum!

Here's what I ended up with, followed by Tim's code for anyone who may need it:

**Send a `System.Exception` from client to server**

```
Public Class Client
  Private Sub ClientTest()
    Dim i As Integer

    Try
      i = String.Empty

    Catch ex As Exception
      Client.Create.Call(Sub(S As IService)
                           S.Log(LogLevels.Error, ex.Message, ex.ToBytes)
                         End Sub)
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class



<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IService
  <OperationContract> Sub Log(Level As LogLevels, Message As String, Data As Byte())
End Interface



Public Class Service
  Implements IService

  Public Sub Log(Level As LogLevels, Message As String, Data As Byte()) Implements IService.Log
    ' Log4Net logger created separately, out of scope of this question '
    Select Case Level
      Case LogLevels.Debug : Main.Logger.Debug(Message, Data.ToException)
      Case LogLevels.Info : Main.Logger.Info(Message, Data.ToException)
      Case LogLevels.Warn : Main.Logger.Warn(Message, Data.ToException)
      Case LogLevels.Error : Main.Logger.Error(Message, Data.ToException)
      Case LogLevels.Fatal : Main.Logger.Fatal(Message, Data.ToException)
    End Select
  End Sub
End Class



Public Module Extensions
  <Extension>
  Public Function ToBytes(Instance As Exception) As Byte()
    Using oStream As New MemoryStream()
      With New NetDataContractSerializer
        .Serialize(oStream, Instance)
      End With

      Return oStream.ToArray
    End Using
  End Function



  <Extension>
  Public Function ToException(Data As Byte()) As Exception
    Using oStream As New MemoryStream(Data)
      With New NetDataContractSerializer
        Return .Deserialize(oStream)
      End With
    End Using
  End Function
End Module
```

**Send CLR objects (including generics) to the client**

```
public class NetDataContractOperationBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    public NetDataContractOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operation)
        : base(operation)
    {
    }   

    public NetDataContractOperationBehavior(OperationDescription operation, DataContractFormatAttribute dataContractFormatAttribute)
        : base(operation, dataContractFormatAttribute)
    {
    }   

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns,
        IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new NetDataContractSerializer(name, ns);
    }   

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, XmlDictionaryString name,
        XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return new NetDataContractSerializer(name, ns);
    }
}   



public class UseNetDataContractSerializerAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription description, BindingParameterCollection parameters)
    {
    }   

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description,
        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation proxy)
    {
        ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(description);
    }   

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription description,
        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatch)
    {
        ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(description);
    }   

    public void Validate(OperationDescription description)
    {
    }   

    private static void ReplaceDataContractSerializerOperationBehavior( OperationDescription description)
    {
        DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsOperationBehavior =
        description.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();   

        if (dcsOperationBehavior != null)
        {
            description.Behaviors.Remove(dcsOperationBehavior);
            description.Behaviors.Add(new NetDataContractOperationBehavior(description));
        }
    }
}


// Then in the service contract, to every method we added the UseNetDataContractSerializer attribute, like so:
[UseNetDataContractSerializer]
[OperationContractAttribute]
Company SaveCompany(CompanyUpdater companyUpdater);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your contract just asks for a generic base exception - the `System.Exception`. If that's the case, then the `DataContractSerializer` will only deserialize that type. It *will not* deserialize anything that extends `Exception`; it will only deserialize exceptions of type `Exception`.

In other words, all the other exceptions that you catch - and you will really never catch a base `System.Exception` type - won't be handled by the contract.

So how can you handle this? Two options:

1. Add other types to your contract. Your contract will still only accept an `Exception`, but if you use the [KnownTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) you can allow objects that sub-type the `Exception` class. This would be your `FaultException`, your `NullReferenceException`, or anything else you want. You can also check, inside the service, whether the `Exception` is one of these types, cast it and use those other properties that may be present. This is my preferred option, but you need to specify every single type you want to handle as a "Known Type". If a new type comes up, it will fail.
2. Clone your exception into a new `System.Exception`. i.e. create a new base `System.Exception`, put the message, the stack trace, and whatever other values you have from your subclass into it. The new object is of the correct type, so it will deserialize correctly.

Neither option is great, but when you think about it concretely you can't create a contract that accepts `object` and send whatever you want. This is the same thing. You can only deliver types that are known by the deserializer.

Comment: #1 sounds risky. #2 might work, but don't we run into the same problem? That WCF can't serialize/deserialize a `System.Exception`? p.s. I'm using Log4Net at the service end, which as you probably know requires a `System.Exception` object.

Comment: Re #2 no we won't get the same issue. We can deserialize `System.Exception` - it's just that we can't deserialize any subclasses of it without naming them. Test your service by sending a simple exception and it will work.

Comment: I tried sending a `System.Exception` just now, but I get the same `System.InvalidCastException` message as above with `FaultException(Of T)`. Do I need to add some attributes to my `IService` interface? If so, which and where?

Comment: Update the question with your interface and your test client (sending simple exception) and I'll look when I can, or at least someone else will have more to go from.

Comment: Updated. It's pretty straightforward, just about as basic as you can get.

Comment: Are you still sending the invalid cast exception? Or are you sending a simple exception? I.e. `Dim e as Exception`

Comment: Well I'll be Pete. It works. I was sending the thrown `System.Exception`, not creating a new one. Now how did you want to create that new one from the thrown one again?

Comment: I guess I'd create a new, empty one and copy the properties across one by one; otherwise you could find some other way to clone it. But given there are only maybe 6 or 7 properties to copy (right?) I'd just do it manually. However! Beware of the inner exception being a subclass as well; you need to make sure you perform the same process for every inner exception.

Comment: Hmm, the properties are read-only. And using the `InnerException` constructor overload results in the same error as above. This is a sticky one, isn't it?

Comment: Yes kind of frustrating. You could extend the base exception, call it LoggableException, and use that in your contract / send that instead. But at that stage you really don't need to extend Exception at all, just create and object that looks like an exception.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this; I've posted my solution as an answer.